# I can interact with GitHub repo but not Heroku when behind a proxy

Tags: git, heroku, github

I'm trying to get a Heroku rep to work from work. Everything works well from home.

I can use the GitHub repo just fine, but whenever I try to use Heroku I get the following:

```
ssh: heroku.com: no address associated with name
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

this is my `$HOME/.ssh/config`

```
Host heroku.com
HostName heroku.com
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

and from `git config -l`:

```
http.proxy=http://webproxy.<hostname>.net:8080
```

What am I missing?

I'm using git bash in windows 7.

Comment: Why you need to do `ssh` to heroku? Heroku provides command line toolkit to connect and fire all the commands.. have you installed the toolkit to your work machine?